# Multiply 1st array value with 1 and 2nd value with 3 in java

Tags: java, arrays

first time posting so sorry for any inconveniences in advance.

So im making an ISBN checking program but im stuck at this problem. I want to multiply 1st value of the array with 1 then the 2nd with 3, then 1 then 3 and so on. Here is my code so far:

```
        String num = "9783453146976";
        
        //split the string and save to a string array
        String[] splitNum = num.split("");
        
        //create an int array to save the splitten strings after conversion
        int[] intsNum = new int[num.length()];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= (num.length() - 2); i++)
        {
            intsNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitNum[i]);
            
            System.out.print(intsNum[i]);
        }
```

Comment: I guess you are missing the last element, or applied for the given input, the last digit is cutted - `6`. `(num.length() - 2)` is the problematic part - usually you should do `i < num.length()` when starting from zero, i.e. `int i = 0`.

Comment: the last 6 is the a checksum of the previous numbers. You multiply the 1st with 1 and 2nd with 3 and so on. Then you sum them up and you subtract the sum with the next multiplicative of 10 and you get 6.

Comment: Oh I see.. Then you are missing a **flipping multiplier**, and a **store variable**, i.e. `int mult = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 3;`, then `store (+=|*=) mult * intsNum[i];` and once u r finished with the loop u can transform the store and get your answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, first time seeing this. Will try it and see if i succeed :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. You gave me the idea that if the i % 2 == 0; then intsNum[i] *= 1; else intsNum[i] *= 3; and it worked. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, what you are missing here is:

1. A conditional multiplication, based on the index of the digit, assuming we start from **0**(even index), we should apply multiplication by *1*, then going to index **1**(odd index) we apply multiplication by *3*, and so on... This can be achieved by simply checking if the index *%2* returns a `0`(even) or a `1`(odd).
2. You will need to sum all those values up and later on transform that into a **control digit**, i.e. if the sum *%10* is equal to `0`, then control digit is **0**, otherwise it is *10 -* sum *%10*.

If I have to extend the code you gave it will look like this:

```
private static boolean checkISBN(String isbn) {

    if (isbn == null || !isbn.matches("\\d{13}")) {
        return false;
    }

    String[] splitNum = isbn.split("");

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (isbn.length() - 2); i++)
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(splitNum[i]) * (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 3);
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(splitNum[splitNum.length - 1]) == (sum % 10 == 0 ? 0 : 10 - sum % 10);
}
```

Another way around would be to use the **Stream API**. A basic implementation that follows [this](https://isbn-information.com/check-digit-for-the-13-digit-isbn.html) guide looks like this:

```
private static boolean checkISBN(String isbn) {

    if (isbn == null || !isbn.matches("\\d{13}")) { // validat that the input contains of exactly 13 digits
        return false;
    }

    // parse the digits as integers
    int[] digits = Arrays.stream(isbn.split(""))
                         .mapToInt(s -> s.charAt(0) - '0')
                         .toArray();

    // calcuate the control digit
    int controlDigit = IntStream.range(0, digits.length - 1)
                                .mapToObj(i -> digits[i] * (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 3))
                                .reduce(Integer::sum)
                                .map(sum -> sum % 10 == 0 ? 0 :  10 - sum % 10)
                                .orElse(-1);

    // validate the control digit
    return digits[digits.length - 1] == controlDigit;
}
```